# read-only file system in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, filesystems, minikube

I'm trying to create a directory in /lib/modules, in minikube:

```
minikube ssh -- sudo mkdir -p /lib/modules/x.x.x/build
```

but it gives me error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/lib/modules/x.x.x': Read-only file system
ssh: Process exited with status 1
```

I also try to solve the problem using mounting but it gives me error too:

```
read-only file system: unknown
```

Anyone have any ideas?